# How to handle Humantask without Minaserver in JBPM 5

Tags: apache, drools, jbpm

I'm using apache mina server to process my workflow.
But when too many processes are launched the Mina server is occupying much of JVM and i couldnt progress further.

```
One instance of "org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketSession" loaded by 
"org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader @ 0xb9b10d58" occupies 685,361,840 (68.96%) bytes.
The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

1.So is there any other alternative to Mina..?

2.How to handle my human task without Mina..?

Kindly suggest a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two alternatives to Apache Mina currently supported in jBPM 5.2
 - LocalTaskService: runs locally, next to your process engine
 - HornetQ: uses HornetQ messages for communication between client and server

Kris